# FBA - problem with adding asnet membership users to Sharepoint groups

Tags: asp.net, authentication, permissions

I have one farm with two web application ("training" and "test") which are installed od 2 servers (for NLB purpose). 
Web apps use claims based auth (win & fba). 
Both web applications use same aspnetdb database on third server. 
When I want to add aspnetmembership user to "test" SP group (e.g. "admins" or "team members") everything pass ok, but when I want to add same user to "training" SP group, i  got error "User does not exist or it is not unique".

Above thing is totally weird because I manage to login with that user(on "training" web app), but adding to "training" SP group is not possible.

PLEASE any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In meantime I found problem source. For some mysterious reason web.config is rewritten with "default" file from folder above "SP web application folder" (that is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories) and while it does that it change my defined machinekey with some "its" value and that results with mess.

To fix problem I returned my machinekey to "my values" and everything works again ok, but I don't know reason why it rewrite web configs, and does that in 00:00 hours - every few days.

I also check "MachineKey" property in IIS 7.5 and everything is setted in the way that machine key MUST NOT be auto generated.

Any hint?

Comment: Sorry for giving answer to my question, but this is important if you use FBA, so I wanna share it. Problem which I experienced IS related with Sharepoint Healt Analyzer rule! More info how solve thing you can read here 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/0d4a9a65-a208-45a7-a082-fc881957cdc0

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated web.config for both content web applications?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately this didn't help.